# Rails form and time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, timezone

In my app I have a form for creating shifts with a time.select. However the time displayed in views is wrong by one hour, and the time as shown in the database is wrong by two hours. If I select the start_time to be 10:00 and stop_time to be 12:00, it shows up as 9:00-11:00 in the view, and as 08:00-10:00 when I check in console.

I want the time to correspond to the system time. Typing Time.now in console gives correct time. I am very confused.

What exactly is wrong and how can I fix this?

I use rails 5 and sqlite database.

form:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Start %>
    <%= f.time_select :start_time, {minute_step: 30} %>
  </div>
  <br>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Stop %>
    <%= f.time_select :stop_time, {minute_step: 30} %>
  </div>
```

application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Stockholm'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
config.active_record.time_zone_aware_types = [:datetime, :time]
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a quick fix:
Add different names in the select box, with the correct time zones, but let the database save it in the 0 time zone.

Controller:

```
@start_times_correct = Model.pluck(:start_time).map{|value| [value.in_time_zone('Stockholm'), value]}
```

View:

```
= f.select(:start_time, options_for_select(@start_times_correct))
```

Note: This works in rails 4, I hope this is available in rails 5, too. You can also use `strftime` to the edited value to customize how the date is displayed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is the type of solution I'd like to avoid. Hopefully there is a more stable fix.

Comment: Mysql provides time zones in the database, if you are not working with a db that existed before, you could look into that